# Ubuntu Server 14.04 - 64 bit version OK for old AMD64 machine?

Tags: server, 64-bit, amd-processor

I've got an old AMD64 machine (AMD Athlon 64 3000) I'd like to run Ubuntu Server 14.04 on.  However, I see there's no longer an AMD64 version.  Will 14.04 be a problem, or should I just use v. 12.04 LTS AMD64 instead?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso) you will find the amd64 image.

Comment: Awesome - thanks (didn't see that on the main 14.04 server download page)

Comment: Actually, on closer examination, I was looking for this: [Ubuntu Server 14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-server-amd64.iso), but without your answer I never would have know where to look.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I corrected the link on my answer.